# ADFS allows to login only to Office 365

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, adfs

I need to authenticate users on my web application using AD FS, but when they are redirected from my website to the ADFS login page they receive a page with error and they cannot introduce their credentials.

My federation configuration looks as follows:

```
issuer=https://sts.mynetwork.com/adfs/ls/
realm=https://localhost/
```

And having this configuration user gets redirected to AD FS login page which doesn't allow him to do anything, since there is an error and no fields for credentials.

When I change my federated configuration to this:

```
issuer=https://sts.mynetwork.com/adfs/ls/
realm=urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline
```

Users are able to login, but they are logged in to Office 365 only.
So I assume that the server configuration doesn't allow AD FS to external websites, but to the Office 365. How to configure AD FS so that external websites will be able to use AD FS authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The ADFS is not premises, AD is managed only on Office 365 and that's why allowing external relying parties cannot be changed.